# Multiple Domains and ipandlanguageredirect

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

i have an Multi Tree Setup with 2 Domains. I use ipandlanguageredirect to adress the correct Language based on the ip to the users.

The configuration of ipandlaguageredirect is done in the extensionmanager so the config is globally configured. If the redirect is done now for the second domain, it got redirected to the first domain.

How can i achieve that a redirect within domain 2 is not redirected to domain 1?

Comment: It may make sense to ask here instead: https://github.com/einpraegsam/ipandlanguageredirect/issues

Comment: Yes, but i thought maybe someone else has an answer before bothering the author. Btw. are you getting payed to be that helpful - you are always one of the first answering in slack and now here :) - thx for your efforts

Comment: It may make sense to ask the author directly and then post the answer here to have it found by a wider audience. I get the feeling that you won't get an answer here. And no, I'm not paid for this, I do this voluntarily. :-)

Comment: Late response from me, but i totally forgot about the issue. I did a pull request for the extension to set the configuration by typoscript so it is configurable per site. But the whole extension was refactored in the meantime by the author, so the handling is now totally different.